# Is there a way to handle missing values with ttestBF() in R?

Tags: r, missing-data, bayesian

`ttestBF()` from the `BayesFactor` package throws the following error when trying to analyse data with missing values:

```
> ttestBF(formula = Level2 ~ Completers, r = sqrt(2)/2, data = tib)
Error in checkFormula(formula, data, analysis = "indept") : 
  Dependent variable must not contain missing or infinite values.
```

Despite being mentioned in [its documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BayesFactor/vignettes/manual.html#functions), adding argument `is.na` to the `ttestBF()` command does not change anything (but perhaps it's my fault because I don't know how to apply it):

```
> ttestBF(formula = Level2 ~ Completers, r = sqrt(2)/2, is.na = TRUE, data = tib)
Error in checkFormula(formula, data, analysis = "indept") : 
  Dependent variable must not contain missing or infinite values.
In addition: Warning message:
data coerced from tibble to data frame
```

My questions:

- Is there a way to handle missing values with `ttestBF()` from the `BayesFactor` package?
- If yes, how?

---

Reproducible data:

```
nn <- 100 # total sample size (both Completers and Non Completers)

# create tibble with 2 level samples (completers & non completers), 50 each
tib <- tibble::tibble(Completers = rep(c(1, 0), each = nn/2),
                      Level = c(sample(1:9, 50, replace = TRUE,
                                             prob = c(57/1043*100, 275/1043*100,
                                                      398/1043*100, 199/1043*100,
                                                      72/1043*100, 27/1043*100,
                                                      12/1043*100, 2/1043*100,
                                                      1/1043*100)),
                                      sample(1:9, 50, replace = TRUE,
                                             prob = c(57/1043*100, 275/1043*100,
                                                      398/1043*100, 199/1043*100,
                                                      72/1043*100, 27/1043*100,
                                                      12/1043*100, 2/1043*100,
                                                      1/1043*100))))

# Value labels
expss::val_lab(tib$Completers) = expss::num_lab("
                                 1 Completers
                                 0 Non Completers")


expss::val_lab(tib$Level) = expss::num_lab("1 A
                                            2 B
                                            3 C
                                            4 D
                                            5 E
                                            6 F
                                            7 G
                                            8 H
                                            9 I")

# Copy 2nd column into 3rd and call it Level2
tib$Level2 <- tib$Level

# Insert single missing value (NA)
tib[3, 2] = NA
```

Output with no missing values:

```
> BayesFactor::ttestBF(formula = Level ~ Completers, r = sqrt(2)/2, data = tib)
Bayes factor analysis
--------------
[1] Alt., r=0.707 : 0.3507102 ±0.02%

Against denominator:
  Null, mu1-mu2 = 0 
---
Bayes factor type: BFindepSample, JZS

Warning message:
data coerced from tibble to data frame
```

Output with missing values:

```
> BayesFactor::ttestBF(formula = Level2 ~ Completers, r = sqrt(2)/2, data = tib)
Error in checkFormula(formula, data, analysis = "indept") : 
  Dependent variable must not contain missing or infinite values.
In addition: Warning message:
data coerced from tibble to data frame
```

Output with missing values and argument `is.na = TRUE`:

```
> BayesFactor::ttestBF(formula = Level2 ~ Completers, r = sqrt(2)/2, is.na = TRUE, data = tib)
Error in checkFormula(formula, data, analysis = "indept") : 
  Dependent variable must not contain missing or infinite values.
In addition: Warning message:
data coerced from tibble to data frame
```

---

Sources:

- Generate data with Likert scale: [stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/374492/252635)
- Add value labels: [r-project](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expss/vignettes/labels-support.html)

---

`sessioninfo::session_info()` extract:

```
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
 os       macOS Monterey 12.5.1
 rstudio  2022.07.1+554 Spotted Wakerobin (desktop)

 package      * version    date (UTC) lib source
 BayesFactor  * 0.9.12-4.4 2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 expss        * 0.11.1     2022-01-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 tibble       * 3.1.8      2022-07-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove NA from your data:

```
BayesFactor::ttestBF(formula = Level2 ~ Completers, r = sqrt(2)/2, data = filter(tib, !is.na(Level2) & !is.na(Completers))
```